# Nomenclature: What is the proper term to describe the probability of event A divided by the probability of event B?

Tags: probability, terminology

I have a hidden markov model that scores the probability of various state sequences (paths). For simplicity, I will talk about a state sequence as an event. I am calculating how much more probable one event (state sequence) is compared to another event (state sequence).

What is the accurate term for that ratio? My intuition is call it "likelihood ratio", but that term [appears to be in use for something else](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Likelihood-ratio_test)

Comment: You might say something like "relative probability" or "ratio of probabilities" or "probability ratio", though in particular situations other terms might apply.

Answer (score 2):

You could call it the [odds](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Odds) of event A versus event B.